# Deep Object Equality of only own Object's Properties in Chai

Tags: javascript, chai

I have an object that I would like to do a deep comparison against another object in [chaijs](http://chaijs.com/). The trouble is that one object has a large number of enumerable properties and the other object is a simple, straightforward object (`{}`).

For example, I have `expect(obj1).to.eql(obj2);` where `obj1` is an object with many additional enumerable properties that a library added and `obj2` was simply created via `var obj2 = { someValue: true }`.

This problem can be solved by abusing `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` like so

```
expect(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1))).to.eql(obj2);
```

but that is a pretty lame hack. I can't image that I am the first one to run into this predicament but my searches have turned up empty. What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: So to be clear: you want to compare only the object's own properties, and not properties added to the prototype chain by a library?

Comment: @HannesJohansson That is absolutely correct. I simply don't care about the prototype properties for the purpose of some of my tests.

Comment: In that case it's not exactly _enumerable_ properties you want to ignore like it says in the question title, you just want to ignore properties that are not the object's own properties.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [chai-shallow-deep-equal](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-shallow-deep-equal/). It does not perform full equality check, but check that second object contains set of properties of first object.

Here's usage example:

```js
var chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-shallow-deep-equal'));

var obj1 = {name: 'Michel', language: 'javascript'};
var obj2 = {name: 'Michel'};
var obj3 = {name: 'Michel', age: 43};

expect(obj1).to.shallowDeepEqual(obj2); // true
expect(obj1).to.shallowDeepEqual(obj3); // false, age is undefined in obj1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a projection of the object you want to test, which only contains "own" (not from the prototype chain) properties, and comparing that for equality.

```
var projection = {};

for (var key in obj1) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        projection[key] = obj1[key];
    }
}

expect(projection).to.eql(obj2);
```

You could extract that projection code into a test utility function.

Comment: This is a decent solution but doesn't really work with the chai ecosystem without turning it into a plugin.

e.g
`var objs = [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ]`
`expect(objs).to.contain(obj2);` still fails as I would have to manually iterate through all objects and remove their prototype properties (apply your fix).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Chai, but looking through their API it doesn't seem that there is any built-in support for this. If you extract my code into a utility function, you could always use it in conjunction with the array `map` method to map an original array of objects into an array of projections. I can't see a smoother solution, sorry.